# Find link in specific tags using python, beautiful soup and lambda functions

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lambda

I have the following html and I am using bs4 beautiful soup in python 3 to extract all hrefs from links that are located inside a specific tag: . It should not be important if there might me more than one or no link nested in the . Furthermore, there would be another step where I filter out links that don't have the "base.html" ending.

```
<article>
   <a href='link/base.html'>click me!</a>
</article>
...
<article>
   <a href='link2/base.html'>click me!</a>
</article>
...
<article>
   <a href='link3/base.html'>click me!</a>
</article>
```

This is my code

```
page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

articles = page.find_all(name="article")

article_links = map(lambda article: article.a, articles)

article_links = map(lambda tag: tag.get('href'), article_links)

article_links = filter(lambda link: 'base.html' in link, article_links)

article_links = map(lambda link: url + link, article_links)
```

However, this results in an

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get''

at the `.get('href')` part in line 4. Other variations result in different errors. It needs to be lambda functions. Preferably, I would also like to combine the first two lambda functions into one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why to use lambda, so just in case select your targets more specific with `css selectors` and iterate result set with `list comprehension`:

```
[url+a['href'] for a in page.select('article a[href*="base.html"]')]
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.example.com/'
html = '''<article>
   <a href='link/base.html'>click me!</a>
</article>
...
<article>
   <a href='link2/base.html'>click me!</a>
</article>
...
<article>
   <a href='link3/base.html'>click me!</a>
</article>'''

page = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

[url+a['href'] for a in page.select('article a[href*="base.html"]')]
```

#### Output

```
['http://www.example.com/link/base.html',
 'http://www.example.com/link2/base.html',
 'http://www.example.com/link3/base.html']
```